# Ubuntu 14.04_64 Display Problem

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

Please somebody help me out to configure my graphics on hp laptop with 14.04 LTS, Its uses Intel HD3000 & Nvidia 630M in hybrid mode. its works perfectly on win7 & my earlier Ubuntu 12.04x64. After the installation of 14.04LTSx64 i am unable to configure correctly.

Comment: just download the linux driver for linux on amd website and install catalyst. u can use the open source driver aswell, but then you won't have the option to choose which graphic card you want at any given moment

Comment: as far as i am having the Nividia card how its possible to install AMD catalyst......?

Comment: err my mistake. i meant u to install the nvidia driver.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same problem I'm having with Nvidia and Ubuntu kernel 3.13.0 (to check your kernel version issue "uname -r" in the terminal) [How do I update to Ubuntu kernel 3.13.0 on 12.04 LTS without breaking the Nvidia graphics driver?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/499448/how-do-i-update-to-ubuntu-kernel-3-13-0-on-12-04-lts-without-breaking-the-nvidia)

The only thing I could find on this was patching the kernel, details are on this Nvidia forum https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/644906/linux/331-20-on-3-13-rc1-kernel/ I don't think this is a perfect solution so go ahead with it at your own peril.

My solution was reverting back to a previous kernel, I'm not sure if this is possible on 14.04. Please be careful you don't want to remove a kernel without having a previous kernel installed although you may be able to install an older kernel with a new one installed so sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.5... The working kernel that I'm using is linux-image-3.5.0 (specifically linux-image-3.5.0-52-generic). You can check what previous kernels are installed by either;

typing the following and hitting TAB

```
apt-get remove linux-image-
```

Or issuing this command

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

But please note that I'm receiving a warning that security updates for the kernel and graphics drivers won't be available after August. I think we might have to wait until this is fixed by the Ubuntu team.

Answer (score 0):

Visit the link below. I hope you could find your answer there.
http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html#Ubuntu

Comment: on my earlier 12.04 i have been using bumblebee successfully, after the 14.04 upgrade, decide to give a try on nvidia prime. If the nvidia prime can't be worked out properly i will definitely give a try on this............

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please DO NOT install ati catalyst drive, you have a nvidia/intel card.
Always prefer the driver whitin additional drivers tab (Software Sources).

The link bellow may be helpful:

[Ubuntu Community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HybridGraphics)